# Can we change BIOS settings from Windows?

Tags: windows, bios

My computer stays off when the power goes off.  I want to change the BIOS setting so that it turns on after the power comes back on.

Can I change that from within Windows?

The Model is [PowerEdge T100](http://www1.ap.dell.com/au/en/business/servers/server-poweredge-t100/pd.aspx?refid=server-poweredge-t100&cs=aubsd1&s=bsd)

Comment: What make and model of computer do you have?

Comment: i have added in the Post

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can we edit bios properties from desktop?](http://superuser.com/questions/112424/can-we-edit-bios-properties-from-desktop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to make changes in the BIOS settings. This [article](http://support.ap.dell.com/support/topics/global.aspx/support/dsn/en/document?c=au&cs=aubsd1&dl=false&l=en&s=bsd&docid=36A6D75A79524337AC21BE95E3FB44C5&doclang=en) describes how to access the BIOS settings on a Dell PC. You'll have to search through the settings to find what you need, but it should be obvious when you do find it. If you see settings you don't understand leave them alone. It's possible to prevent your computer from booting with the wrong settings. Of course you can always put them back to the original setting.

If you mess it up, this [article](http://supportapj.dell.com/support/topics/global.aspx/support/dsn/en/document?docid=4C1BF720A3E78F92E040A68F5A2811BE) walks you through restoring the default BIOS settings on Dell PCs.

Print the articles or write down the instructions before trying this as you won't have access to the Internet on this PC while you are doing it. I've found it's best to make one change at a time until you know what you are doing. Always write down the original setting so you can go back if something goes wrong.

Comment: but i want within windows not at restarting. i use RDP for server so i don't have access to my server room

Comment: On every PC I have ever used the the BIOS settings can only be changed at startup.

Answer (score 1):

some manufactures give you this capability you'll have to go to their support site find out if your bios supports it.

does this server have the DRAC module? It gives you more options when its a headless server.