# CMOS editor on Windows?

Tags: windows-xp, bios, remote-access, cmos

I need some way to modify BIOS settings in the CMOS memory from within Windows.

Particularly I want to change the "state after power failure" setting through a remote VNC connection.

Mainboard: ASUS P5G41T-M LX2/GB
BIOS: AMI, Version 0408, Date 01/19/2011

OS: Windows XP SP3

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can we edit bios properties from desktop?](http://superuser.com/questions/112424/can-we-edit-bios-properties-from-desktop), [Can I change&update BIOS settings simply from Windows GUI(ring 3)?](http://superuser.com/questions/260229/can-i-changeupdate-bios-settings-simply-from-windows-guiring-3), [Can we change BIOS settings from Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/137021/can-we-change-bios-settings-from-windows)

Comment: @techie007 [http://superuser.com/questions/260229/can-i-changeupdate-bios-settings-simply-from-windows-guiring-3] has a dead link to an ASUS utility which I couldn't locate yet and the other answers are specific to another BIOS or machine

Comment: Yeah the device-specific answers are bad answers (IMO).  The short answer is: In general no, unless your mb manufacturer supplies a tool to do it. Get it from them as asking SU for links to specific software is off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Generally not unless your motherboard/system manufacturer has supplied such software for that purpose. Some do, some don't.

In most cases, adjusting BIOS settings requires that you be at the computer itself. You can try googling for such software, and hope for the best. other than that, I'd say you're out of luck.