# Can I change&update BIOS settings simply from Windows GUI(ring 3)?

Tags: windows, bios

Can I change and update my BIOS settings simply from inside Windows?

Comment: What board are you wanting to do this on?

Comment: Hi, MaQleod, I'm using an average ASUS motherboard.

Comment: AFAIK, the only way to do it (from a technical point of view) is to delegate all BIOS accesses to a device driver in ring0. This is what the official configuration tools do, I'd guess.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can we edit bios properties from desktop?](http://superuser.com/questions/112424/can-we-edit-bios-properties-from-desktop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ASUS boards, you can update the BIOS using their [utility](http://support.asus.com/technicaldocuments/technicaldocuments_content.aspx?no=714) which will run within windows.

Comment: I do hope they spent more time on the actual configuration code than on the horrible appearance...